# How do I store a Python object in memory for use by different processes?

Tags: python, web, memory, python-internals

Here's the situation: I have a massive object that needs to be loaded into memory. So big that if it is loaded in twice it will go beyond the available memory on my machine (and no, I can't upgrade the memory). I also can't divide it up into any smaller pieces. For simplicity's sake, let's just say the object is 600 MB and I only have 1 GB of RAM. I need to use this object from a web app, which is running in multiple processes, and I don't control how they're spawned (a third party load balancer does that), so I can't rely on just creating the object in some master thread/process and then spawning off children. This also eliminates the possibility of using something like POSH because that relies on it's own custom fork call. I also can't use something like a SQLite memory database, mmap or the posix_ipc, sysv_ipc, and shm modules because those act as a file in memory, and this data has to be an object for me to use it. Using one of those I would have to read it as a file and then turn it into an object in each individual process and BAM, segmentation fault from going over the machine's memory limit because I just tried to load in a second copy.

There must be someway to store a Python object in memory (and not as a file/string/serialized/pickled) and have it be accessible from any process. I just don't know what it is. I've looked all over StackOverflow and Google and can't find the answer to this, so I'm hoping somebody can help me out.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "because those act as a file in memory".  Shared memory is a piece of memory, not a file.  You can use that memory to store anything, including an object.  This might not be so obvious in Python, but in C it is.  Does this have to be a Python-only solution, or will you consider a hybrid Python/C or Python/C++ solution to access the object indirectly via C/C++ bindings to an object in shared memory?

Comment: Because those things do act as files in memory, see http://docs.python.org/library/mmap.html for example.

Comment: Would something like Memcached for Python help at all?

Comment: @DerekLitz: *in Python*, they act like a file (or a string).  This means that a Python program using `mmap()` cannot read or write anything but a serialized version of an object.  This is why I mentioned that this restriction is only specific to Python and that a hybrid solution might provide exactly the desired functionality.

Comment: I see.  Your point is that he can when he said he can't, through some not so obvious means.

Comment: what is the structure of that large object? if we knew that and how it is used it might be possible to find a solution to the right problem.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. I understand that it might be possible with C or C++ because of the way they have access to memory, but I would _prefer_ an all Python solution because the company is a Python dev house.

Comment: Also, Memcached has a limit of 1MB per value so that's not really an option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes

Look for shared memory, or Server process.  After re-reading your post Server process sounds closer to what you want.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory

Comment: At the bottom of the Server Process section is this:

"Server process managers are more flexible than using shared memory objects because they can be made to support arbitrary object types. Also, a single manager can be shared by processes on different computers over a network."

That is extremely interesting and potentially exactly what I need, but I can't seem to find good documentation on how to do it. Searching for "python server process" yields vague results. Do you know of any good resources?

Comment: In response to my last comment it's actually just in a different section on the same page: http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager.connect

Awesome! That is totally going to work for me.

Answer (score 2):

> There must be someway to store a Python object in memory (and not as a
>   file/string/serialized/pickled) and have it be accessible from any
>   process.

That isn't the way in works.  Python object reference counting and an object's internal pointers do not make sense across multiple processes.

If the data doesn't have to be an actual Python object, you can try working on the raw data stored in mmap() or in a database or somesuch.

Answer (score 1):

I would implement this as a C module that gets imported into each Python script. Then the interface to this large object would be implemented in C, or some combination of C and Python.