# execute parts of script in PyCharm and keep data frame etc. in memory

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23441657/pycharm-run-only-part-of-my-python-file). Unfortunately, this does not work if the executed code selection has dependencies on previous code (e.g. a data frame created from a csv file).

How can I execute parts of a script and keep, for example, a data frame in memory (a session?) similar to R or even SAS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use object from a previously run code in a different process, you need to save it somewhere.

you can use [Pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) - a module that will allow you to save an object in its current state and read it again (unpickle) in a different process.

Comment: Sure but I simply want to reduce the time it takes to read in a 150MB pandas data frame. Like in R I want to keep it in memory and just re-plot after some minute changes. Surely that must be possible?

Comment: Please look at Raymond Hettinger Answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469272/how-do-i-store-a-python-object-in-memory-for-use-by-different-processes